# css add shadow effort to iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

I want to use css shadow effort, my html is like this

```
<div id="contentFrame">
<iframe id="subFrame" src =""></iframe>
</div><!--contentFrame-->
</div><!--pageContent-->
```

the size of `#contentFrame` is the same as `#subFrame` I have add shadow effort to both of them, it works ok when the iframe is empty. but the shadow effort will disappear when the iframe have content in it.

Comment: Can you please make a fiddle: jsfiddle.net?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AY34J/

Comment: I can still see the shadow after adding content to the `iframe`. http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/AY34J/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AY34J/2/ you can remove the js, and the shadow effect will appear.

Comment: I dont get your problem tbh.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AY34J/4/

Comment: why cant I see the content .. X(

Comment: you can get the issue now

Comment: hummm shadow is going behind the content.. try giving padding if you can ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following:

1. The content frame still has the css properties of the shadow effect.
2. The z-index (css property) of the contentFrame is higher than your subFrame.